# How to access to variable in ASPX page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

ASPX:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <%
       int a = 25;
    %>
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" 
         Text='<%#a %>'></asp:Label>
</form>
```

Code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
       DataBind();
    }
}
```

Error:

> The name 'a' does not exist in the current context

Comment: you may perhaps try `<%=a %>`

Comment: It doesn't work that way. `Text='<%#a %>'>` - you just set string to text. I think, you need in code to do it: `<% Label1.Text=a >%`.

Answer (score 0):

Found solution:

ASPX:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" 
         Text="<%#a %>"></asp:Label>
</form>
```

Code behind:

```
public int a;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (!IsPostBack)
   {
      a = 25;
      DataBind();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This way will work..
ASPX:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
         <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
</form>
```

code behind:

```
public int a;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (!IsPostBack)
   {
      a = 25;
    Label1.Text=a.ToString();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

something to note, is that the aspx file is compiled to a class by the the System.Web.UI.Page class which implements IHttpHandler, the created class inherit the aspx.cs/aspx.vb, which explain the **inherits** in the **<%@ Page %>** directive, and by logic, you cannot reference a variable declared in aspx code nugget in code behind.
As a work around, you can declare `protected` members in code behind and access those from code nuggets.